# hour, minutes,seconds to Time_t

Tags: c++, time

I know the Current system time.
I know the estimated time of arrival of a place in the form of hours minutes and seconds.
I need to find the duration of travel. But the estimated time of arrival is in 12 hour format. 
I have to write a program to find the time difference between these two ?
I thought of using difftime(time1,time2)
but this requires the datatype time_t. I know the time in parts. i.e. i know the hours, minutes and seconds separatley. Both current system time and Estimated time of arrival.
I need to find the time difference between the two. The ETA can be after 24 hours. then is there any way i can find out the number of days of travel. Because after 12PM time is set back. hence i'm not able to keep track of the days.
Any solution ?
I work on C++

Comment: What language are you working in ?

Comment: How to convert between these two time representations is highly dependent on language. Which are you using?

Comment: Any suggestions or solutions ???

Comment: If everything is given in 12 hour format, then there is no way to calculate it accurately if it's more than 12 hours.  It cannot be done.

Answer (score 0):

A straight forward way using C/C++.  This is not very robust, but should meet your given requirements.

```
#include <ctime>

tm source;

memset(&source, 0, sizeof(tm));
tm.tm_hour = hour; // 24 hour format, 0 = midnight, 23 = 11pm
tm.tm_min = min;
tm.tm_sec = sec;
tm.tm_mon = month;  // 0 based, 0 = jan, 11 = dec
tm.tm_mday = 10;
tm.tm.year = year;  // current - 1900

time_t src_t = mktime(&source);
time_t now = time(NULL);
```